# Python и VK API: photos.getUploadServer возвращает Access denied

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь загрузить фото в VK-альбом:

```py
def loadPhoto(filename, groupId, albumId, capt=''):
    upSrv = api.photos.getUploadServer(album_id=albumId, group_id=groupId)
```

Но получаю ошибку на первом шаге:

```
vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 200. Access denied. request_params = {
   'method': 'photos.getUploadServer',
   'oauth': '1',
   'v': '5.103',
   'album_id': '272447100',
   'group_id': '-97072243'
}
```

Авторизуюсь по токену пользователя (администратора группы) с правами:

```
photos,friends,wall,groups,offline
```

Свойства целевого альбома:

```
  "id":272447100,
  "thumb_id":457239105,
  "owner_id":-97072243,
  "title":"t3_1",
  "description":"",
  "created":1580074902,
  "updated":1580929831,
  "size":1,
  "thumb_is_last":1,
  "can_upload":1,
  "upload_by_admins_only":0,
  "comments_disabled":0
```

При тех же условиях (user token, группа), photos.get**Wall**UploadServer работает корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Великолепный Агент Поддержки #10646 ВК решил проблему в одну строчку:
[image: Ответ Агента Поддержки]

Оказалось, дело в разнице между параметрами `owner_id` и `group_id`:

`owner_id` принимает и положительные значения (**ID пользователей**), и отрицательные (**ID сообществ**).

`group_id` — это только положительные значения.

`group_id = mod(owner_id)` (если в `owner_id` идентификатор группы)